Why can't I add or remove event listeners in JavaScript
I am making a basic rock paper scissors game. I am making it so when you hover over an option it rises, and when you click it, it should stay in the air, but I am unable to remove the event listener.
<main>
    <h2>Choose A Play:</h2>

    <div id="rock" onmouseover="hover('rock')" onmouseout="out('rock')" onclick="select('rock')">
        Rock
    </div>

    <div id="paper" onmouseover="hover('paper')" onmouseout="out('paper')" onclick="select('paper')">
        Paper
    </div>

    <div id="scissors" onmouseover="hover('scissors')" onmouseout="out('scissors')" onclick="select('scissors')">
        Scissors
    </div>


</main>

#rock {
  background-color: #252422;

  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fffcf2;

  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;

  padding: 25px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 50px;

  float: left;
}

#paper {
  background-color: #252422;

  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fffcf2;

  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;

  padding: 25px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 50px;

  float: left;
}

#scissors {
  background-color: #252422;

  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fffcf2;

  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;

  padding: 25px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-right: 50px;

  float: right;
}

let options = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];


function hover(elementId) {
    document.getElementById(elementId).style.marginTop = '10px';
}

function out(elementId) {
    document.getElementById(elementId).style.marginTop = '50px';
}

function select(elementId) {
    document.getElementById(elementId).style.backgroundColor = '#ffba08';
    document.getElementById(elementId).style.marginTop = '10px';

    let userChoice = options.filter(x => x === elementId);
    let userNoPick = options.filter(x => x !== elementId);
    revokeListeners(userChoice, userNoPick);
}

function revokeListeners(userSelection, userNoSelection) {

    document.getElementById(userSelection).removeEventListener('mouseout', out)
}

I didn't include all of the CSS so it looks a bit funky.
Expected: When a div is clicked it turns yellow then floats in the air.
Result: The event listener does not get deleted and the box drops again.


Don't use inline event listeners, use addEventListener instead. 2) Don't remove the event listener, use something else to manage state. Eg set at data attribute of clicked on the element, then your mouse out listener can use that to check if it should do something. That way you can then re-enable the mouse out functionality at will


You can't remove an event listener with removeEventListener that was not added with addEventListener (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener). That being said, don't remove something you might want later.
I've used a data attribute to manage the selected state. Though another thing to consider would be using hiding radio buttons in label element, which is an inbuilt way of managing mutually exclusive selections
I've also dropped inline listeners to a more modern approach


let options = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];

//use the data attribute as a selector to add event listeners
document.querySelectorAll('[data-status]').forEach(function(el){
  //Click
   el.addEventListener("click",function(){
    this.style.backgroundColor = '#ffba08';
    this.style.marginTop = '10px';
    this.dataset.status = "selected";

    let userChoice = options.filter(x => x === this.id);
    let userNoPick = options.filter(x => x !== this.id);
  });
  

  //Hover
  el.addEventListener("mouseover",function(){
    this.style.marginTop = '10px';
  });
  
  
  //Mouse out
    el.addEventListener("mouseout",function(){
    if(this.dataset.status !== "selected") {
      this.style.marginTop = '50px';
    }
  });
  
});
#rock {
  background-color: #252422;

  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fffcf2;

  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;

  padding: 25px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 50px;

  float: left;
}

#paper {
  background-color: #252422;

  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fffcf2;

  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;

  padding: 25px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 50px;

  float: left;
}

#scissors {
  background-color: #252422;

  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fffcf2;

  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;

  padding: 25px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-right: 50px;

  float: right;
}
<main>
    <h2>Choose A Play:</h2>

    <div id="rock" data-status>
        Rock
    </div>

    <div id="paper" data-status>
        Paper
    </div>

    <div id="scissors" data-status>
        Scissors
    </div>


</main>



Or the HTML/CSS only approach, then you can leave JavaScript to handle the game logic. Leave the presentation to CSS


label {
 background-color: #252422;

  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fffcf2;

  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;

  padding: 25px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 50px;

  float: left;
}

label:hover, label:has(:checked) {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

label:has(:checked) {
  background-color:#ffba08;
}

label > input {
  display:none;
}

#rock {
 /* background-color: #252422;

  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fffcf2;

  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;

  padding: 25px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 50px;

  float: left;*/
}

#paper {
  /*background-color: #252422;

  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fffcf2;

  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;

  padding: 25px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 50px;

  float: left;*/
}

#scissors {
 /* background-color: #252422;

  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fffcf2;

  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;

  padding: 25px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-right: 50px;*/

  float: right;
}
<main>
    <h2>Choose A Play:</h2>

    <label id="rock">
        Rock
        <input type="radio" name="game" value="rock">
    </label>

    <label id="paper">
        Paper
        <input type="radio" name="game" value="paper">
    </label>

    <label id="scissors">
        Scissors
        <input type="radio" name="game" value="scissors">
    </label>


</main>




I'm not sure why removeEventListener isn't working. I tried a few different options and one I managed to get work was to replace
 document.getElementById(userSelection).removeEventListener('mouseout', out)

with
document.getElementById(userSelection).onmouseout = undefined;

A little hacky, but it works.
Hope that helps!

Mind if I ask why my answer got downvoted? I much prefer Jon P's solution by the way, just curious?

Unfortunately drive by down votes happen. I've been on the receiving end of them, even on accepted answers.  Perhaps because you described it as hacky. At least it is simple if a little hacky.
